# golang Define struct once and use it in another struct definition

Tags: go, struct, coding-style

Define struct once and use it in another struct defination

```
type FormAction struct {
    Data bool `yaml:"data,omitempty" json:"data,omitempty"`
    Self bool `yaml:"self,omitempty" json:"self,omitempty"`
    Blob bool `yaml:"blob,omitempty" json:"blob,omitempty"`
}
type ManifestSrc struct {
    Data bool `yaml:"data,omitempty" json:"data,omitempty"`
    Self bool `yaml:"self,omitempty" json:"self,omitempty"`
    Blob bool `yaml:"blob,omitempty" json:"blob,omitempty"`
}
type PrefetchSrc struct {
    Data bool `yaml:"data,omitempty" json:"data,omitempty"`
    Self bool `yaml:"self,omitempty" json:"self,omitempty"`
    Blob bool `yaml:"blob,omitempty" json:"blob,omitempty"`
}
```

how we can reduce the redundancy of same members ?

Comment: You can do `type ManifestSrc FormAction`. See: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_declarations

Comment: …or use [field embedding](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#embedding). I would really recommend to gain at least basic knowledge of the language before embarking on non-toy tasks.

Comment: @mkopriva @kostix
this won't work in unmarshal stuff. Since we don't have anything to map in YAML and json
```
FormAction: 
   Data: true
ManifestSrc:
   Self: true
```

Comment: @YashKatta *"Since we don't have anything to map in YAML and json..."* -- That was not part of the question, and even from the comment it is unclear to me what the exact problem with the suggested solutions is. Please update your question by explaining why the suggested solutions aren't enough and provide the code where you have attempted to use said suggestions. And include any information on the errors that you've encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most idiomatic way of defining the same fields in multiple structs without repeating yourself is to use embedding, because it still allows you to add other fields, eg:

```golang
type entity struct {
    Data bool `yaml:"data,omitempty" json:"data,omitempty"`
    Self bool `yaml:"self,omitempty" json:"self,omitempty"`
    Blob bool `yaml:"blob,omitempty" json:"blob,omitempty"`
}
type FormAction struct {
    entity
}
type ManifestSrc struct {
    entity
}
type PrefetchSrc struct {
    entity
    AnotherField string // For example
}
```